# PHP cURL not posting data properly

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to create a php script that will pass a post variable to a form online and return the information. I have successfully done this using the command line with the following command:

```
curl --data "cid=800.10" http://online.starmont.ca/java/www?html=main
```

Unfortunately I can not seem to get this to work with php. If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is the PHP script I currently have.

```
<?php

//set up a connection variable for the page you will post data to
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://online.starmont.ca/java/www?html=main');

//curl basic setup
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//$_POST variables to pass
$post_item = 'cid='.strip_tags($_POST['800.10']);

//format the $post_items into a string
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//send the $_POST data to the new page
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

print ($result);
curl_close($curl_connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to set

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

In order to make curl perform a `POST` request.

For more information: http://www.php.net/curl_setopt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put:

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);

BEFORE

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

otherwise it seems to send no data! (for me anyway)